# I want to map , but my mappings is in excel file, how can i do it?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, mapping

```
size = df['Symbol'].map({'circle':25, 'triangle':20})
```

This is what i want to do

**Excel file number one:**

| Symbol | Size |
| --- | --- |
| circle | 25 |
| triangle | 20 |
| circle | 25 |
| circle | 25 |
| triangle | 20 |
| square | 10 |

So here i am mapping from the column symbol to column size.
for example wherever is the symbol circle in the symbol column the mapping is pasting 25 in the size column.
But because there is a lot of symbols and i have them in excel number two, how can i do it without type in them one by one .
I want to do the same thing as above but throw the excel sheets

**Excel file number two**

| Symbol_sign | Number |
| --- | --- |
| Triangle | 20 |
| circle | 25 |
| square | 10 |

Comment: Not enough information to understand the real problem.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: @furas size = df['Symbol'].map({'circle':25, 'triangle':20})
size = df['Symbol'].map(['size'].get)
df['_size'] = df['Symbol'].map(['size'].get)

Comment: put it all in question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

So let's understand the issue quickly.
You have a pandas DataFrame `df` that has a column named `'Symbol'`, right?

Let's say `df['Symbol']` is something like:

```py
>>> df["Symbol"]
0      circle
1    triangle
2      circle
3      circle
4    triangle
5      square
```

and you have an Excel sheet (let's say named `mapping.xlsx`) that has the size info for each symbol for example:

[image]

and you want to map the sizes from `mapping.xlsx` to the symbols in your DataFrame `df`.

What you need to do simply is:

```py
# read your excel sheet as a DataFrame: (make sure you install openpyxl)
mapping = pd.read_excel('mapping.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index_col=0)
# you can treat "mapping" as a dict
size = df['Symbol'].map(mapping['size'].get)
# and if you want to add a size column to your DataFrame:
df['size'] = df['Symbol'].map(mapping['size'].get)
```

Comment: Basicly i have 2 excel files, and the Symbol column in the first excel has the same values with the second excel column symbol sign. and what i want is to create another one column name size where i will map the numbers , and i want symbol_sign column to check if where are the same values in symbol column to map them in column size

Comment: Consider `df` to be Excel number 1, and `mapping` to be Excel number 2 and try the above solution, so you can use Excel 2 instead of the dict you posted in your code.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the query, you can import the excel sheet as a `.csv file` and then convert it into a key-value dictionary before passing it to the `map` function.

I assume your excel file looks something like this:

[image]

(credit for image:Mina Melek)

Having a column for `symbol` and a column for `size`.
You now gotta import it:

```
import pandas as pd
symbols_sizes = pd.read_csv('path')
```

Now as map function can't be applied to a dataframe, you need to convert it to a dictionary first.

```
dictionary = {}
for symbol,size in zip(symbols_sizes[:,0],symbols_sizes[:,1]):
    dictionary[symbol] = size
```

And wallah!! now you have a dictionary made of all the entries in your excel file.

(This should also take care of all the duplicates in the original sheet because the dictionary doesn't allow duplication)

Comment: Basicly i have 2 excel files, and the Symbol column in the first excel has the same values with the second excel column symbol sign. and what i want is to create another one column name size where i will map the numbers , and i want symbol_sign column to check if where are the same values in symbol column to map them in column size